# Loop seems to terminate before reaching the null character in C

Tags: c, arrays, null-character

Below is a section of a Tokenizer I built. The user types a string they wish to tokenize, that string is stored into a char array, and a null character ('\0') is placed as soon as the string ends. That section of the code seems to work fine after having tested it a few times.

The problem I'm getting occurs later on in the code when I make an array *(tokenArray)* of arrays *(newToken)*. I use functions to get number of tokens and token length.

I entered the string "testing pencil calculator." I then store each token into an array. The problem is when I go to print the contents of the array, the loop that I have printing stops before it should.

Here's a sample input/output. My comments (not in code) noted by

```
$testing pencil calculator //string entered

complete index: 0        //index of the entire array, not the tokenized array
token length: 7          //length of 1st token "testing" 
pointer: 0xbf953860 
tokenIndex: 0            //index of the token array (array of arrays)
while loop iterations: 4 //number of times the while loop where i print is iterated. should be 7
test                     //the results of printing the first token 

complete index: 8                                                
token length: 6          //next token is "pencil"                                                                              
tokenIndex: 1                                                    
while loop iterations: 5 //should be 6                                       
penci                    //stops printing at penci     

complete index: 15                                                  
token length: 10         //final token is "calculator"                                           
pointer: 0xbf953862                                                   
tokenIndex: 2                                                         
while loop iterations: 5 //should be 10                                              
calcu                    //stops printing at calcu
```

for the life of me, I simply cannot figure out why the while loop is exiting before it is supposed to. I doubt this is the only problem with my methodology, but until I can figure this out, I can't address other bugs.

Below is a section of my code that is responsible for this:

from main:

```
  completeString[inputsize] = '\0';   

  char tokenArray[numTokens+1];
  tokenArray[numTokens] = '\0';    
  putTokensInArray(tokenArray, completeString);
```

method where I'm getting errors:

```
char ** putTokensInArray(char tokenArray[], char * completeString){
  int completeIndex = 0;
  int tokenIndex = 0;

  while(tokenArray[tokenIndex] != '\0'){
    int tokenLength = tokenSize(completeString, completeIndex);
    char newToken [tokenLength+1];
    newToken[tokenLength] = '\0';
    tokenArray[tokenIndex] = *newToken;

    printf("\ncomplete index: %d", completeIndex);
    printf("\ntoken length: %d", tokenLength);
    printf("\ntokenIndex: %d\n", tokenIndex);

    int i = 0;
    while(newToken[i] != '\0'){
      newToken[i] = completeString[i + completeIndex];
      i++;
    }
    completeIndex += (tokenLength+1);

    printf("while loop iterations: %d\n", i);

    for(int j = 0; newToken[j] != '\0'; j++){
      printf("%c", newToken[j]);
    }

    tokenIndex++;
    tokenLength = 0;

  }//big while loop 
}//putTokensInArray Method
```

I have tried several things but just cannot get the grasp of it. I'm new to C, so it's entirely possible I'm making pointer mistakes or accessing memory I shouldn't be; on that note, how would I implement a malloc() and free()? I've been doing reading on that and seems to  work, but I'm unable to implement those functions.

Comment: `*newToken` causes undefined behaviour (you read the first character out of `newToken` but you never initialized the contents)

Comment: Also your function is declared to return `char **` but you dont have a `return` statement

Comment: I haven't implemented the return statement yet. 

So what you're saying is that I need to initalize the contents of an array when I make it? So I would just loop the array and put in a random value in all indexes?

Comment: You can't read out of an array before you put something in it.  Your code has a lot of problems though.  I suspect that you intended for that line to store a pointer to the array, not read the first character of it. But the rest of your code is not set up to store that.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing an uninitialized character array to your function `putTokensInArray`. Later in that function, in the `while` loop condition you are checking for `\0` for every element starting from 0. However since the array is uninitialized, those characters could be ANY characters. There could be a `\0` before the `numTokens+1`th element.

To fix this problem, pass the length of the character array i.e. `numTokens` to the `putTokensInArray` as an additional argument. Then in your while loop, do the following condition check instead:

`while(tokenIndex < numTokens){`

Comment: Thank you. This may sound dumb, but is there a correct or a standard way to initialize contents of an array in C? Do we place -1 into every index or something like that?

Or is this where malloc and free come into play? I'm a beginner so I'm still trying to understand all these things. I appreciate your help!

Comment: @OmarKhalik, initializing a char array is real easy. `char tokenArray[numTokens+1] = "";` This will initialize every element to 0.